# Can I place a comment inside a tag in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, comments

I am looking to display this in my `.aspx` page, without using special character XML tags, can this be achieved?

```
<asp:ServerTag Property1="a"
    Property2="b"
    Property3="c" <%-- Comment why this particular property is necessary --%>
    Property4="d" />
```

However, I am greeted with the error message `Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.` If I use an HTML <!-- --> tag, I'm told the server tag is not well formed.

Is there any other syntax to make this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible, no. The server tags need to be well-formed XML and you can't have tags like that in XML. You can put a comment at the top, of course, like so:

```
<!-- Property2 needed because... -->
<asp:ServerTag Property1="a" Property2="b" Property3="c" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that it must be well-formed XML.  Always helps to know the "why". 

(As I side note, I agree with jdk's comment that a server tag would be better here.)

Answer (score 14):

Put **server-side comment** above your **server-side control**.

- `<!--` client-side comment (html) - appears in html source but not rendered on page
- `<%--` server-side comment - stripped out on server, never sees light of day, browser never knows about it

like this

```
<%-- Usage:
Property2 is xyz... 
Property3 will .. abc. Ignore Property  1 when this is set. etc
--%>
<asp:ServerTag Property1="a"
    Property2="b"
    Property3="c" 
    Property4="d" />
```

It's just like putting source code comments above your functions.

Think "server to server". It will make the difference between your HTML source looking like
**cluttered** with "pass through" html comment `<!--`:

> <!-- Property usage: abc, def, ...xyz -->
>   Rendered server control contents.

vs. the **cleaner** stripped out " `<%--` source:

> Rendered server control contents.

Less bandwidth with latter too. No extraneous (and confusing to user) comments in HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily like that but you may want to consider decorating the property in c# to let the user know its relevance. After that something like resharper (or maybe vs) will give you this information when you try to set it.