# Comments Within an Asp Tag

Tags: asp.net

I know how to comment any code in the ASP page, but I want to ask is this is allowed in ASP to comment the line within any ASP tag. For example:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv01" ControlToValidate="txtName"
  Enabled="False" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Error"
  <%--Some Comments--%>
  ValidationGroup="TestGroup" />
```

I know its very basic question, but couldn't find the answer at the moment. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: why don't you try it yourself first?

Comment: Ok I found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413725/can-i-place-a-comment-inside-a-tag-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't.

You might be able to achieve a similar effect by using a fake attribute/property, but I don't know how well the ASP.NET parser would handle that:

```
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv01" ControlToValidate="txtName"
  Enabled="False" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Error"
  comments="--Some Comments--"
  ValidationGroup="TestGroup" />
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You can't embed `<% %>` inline constructs in server tags. You can't embed them in non-server tags either. In the first case you'll get a compile-time error, in the latter case a 'runtime-error' inasmuch as it will produce bad markup, so `<div  <%-- some comment --%>></div>` will result in that element not being rendered in Chrome where other browsers might handle it differently.

P.S. My original answer addressed the wrong question, due to my own fault.

Comment: Seriously?  You can embed comments WITHIN tags?  It handles < and > correctly?

Comment: @AnnL. Apologies, no, I was too hasty reading the question.